# How to use prettier for formatting markdown files on save?

Tags: vim9script

I am wondering what could be an efficient way to achieve what I asked in the title.

The best I came out with is the following defined in `~/.vim/ftplugin/markdown.vim`:

```
augroup PRETTIER
    autocmd! * <buffer>
    autocmd BufWritePost <buffer> {
    b:win_view = winsaveview()
    silent exe "!prettier --prose-wrap always --print-width 80 --write " .. expand("%")
    edit %
    winrestview(b:win_view)
    echo "File prettified!"
    }
augroup END
```

which works very well.

However, by doing this the file is saved twice as the option `--write` used by `prettier` appear to save the file once prettified.

Also, the content in between `{}` inside the autocommand could be defined in a function. In-fact I did the following:

```
def Prettify()
    b:win_view = winsaveview()
    silent exe "!prettier --prose-wrap always --print-width 80 --write " .. expand("%")
    edit %
    winrestview(b:win_view)
    echo "File prettified!"
enddef

augroup PRETTIER
    autocmd! * <buffer>
    autocmd BufWritePost <buffer> call Prettify()
augroup END
```

but this end up in `E127: Cannot redefine function <SNR<76_Prettify: It is in use`

Comment: Can prettify work as a filter? Then you can use `%!prettify …` to avoid the double-write. For the function error, please share the complete code you used (with autocommand).

Comment: Thanks! By using `silent exe ":%!prettier --prose-wrap always --print-width 80 " .. expand("%")` solved ALL the problems!

Comment: If it's solved, consider posting an answer.

Comment: Related: `:help 'formatprg'`.

Comment: @D.BenKnoble but now I got curious. Why I got E127 with relation to my second question?

Comment: @romainl Interesting, thanks. Is there any advantage in using `'formatprg'` instead of the `Prettify()` function that I defined below?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a more canonical and holistic approach.

Your question is specifically about formatting a buffer on write but formatting is a common thing that can be done in other scenarios and it turns out that Vim has a number of builtin commands and options for that. Setting the relevant options, `:help 'formatprg'` and/or `:help 'formatexpr'`, AS WELL AS (not "instead of") writing your own custom functions would give you a complete formatting solution.

The built-in operator `gq` can be used to format the text covered by the given motion, as in `gqip` or `gggqG`. If `formatprg` is set, then `gq` uses the given external program and, if `formatexpr` is set, it uses the given expression, which means that you can then simply use `gq` manually *or in your autocommand*.

The whole thing would look like this, from the lower-level to the the higher-level:

```
" in autoload/format/markdown.vim
" this is where the formatting is actually done
" with all the filetype/context-relevant specificities
function! format#markdown#FormatExpr()
    " do your thing
endfunction

" in autoload/format.vim
" nothing filetype-specific, here,
" only use gq on the whole buffer
" and restore cursor position
" can be used as-is for any filetype
function! format#FormatWithoutMoving()
    let l:view = winsaveview()
    silent normal! gggqG
    call winrestview(l:view)
endfunction

" in after/ftplugin/markdown.vim
" this is where you tell Vim how to format that specific filetype
" and that it should do it on write
set formatexpr=format#markdown#FormatExpr()
augroup Markdown
    autocmd! * <buffer>
    autocmd BufWritePre <buffer> silent call format#FormatWithoutMoving()
augroup END
```

And, now that you have a dedicated `format#markdown#FormatExpr()`, you can fine-tune your call to `prettier` according to context (range, buffer-local variables, presence of `prettier` or not, error handling, etc.).

Comment: Thanks. after learning formatprg and formatexpr I was actually going towards the route you suggested. But what if `FormatExpr` function takes some argument and in a custom command I would `call format#markdown#FormatExpr(my_arg)`? Wouldn't I lose the win view when invoking my custom command unless I don't save/restore it inside `FormatExpr`, no?

Comment: Yes. My suggestion is to handle the view restoration and the formatting separately but I am not aware of all your circumstances so you might be better off handling the two at the same place. YMMV.

Comment: @Barzi2001, note the difference in autocommand as well, `BufWritePre` is called before buffer is saved, you're using `BufWritePost` which is called after buffer is saved.

Comment: @MaximKim yes, that was what I was initially doing which has been corrected in the self-answer I provided

Answer (score 0):

As requested here is the solution thanks to the insight of @D. Ben Knoble. The trick was to use `%!prettier ...` . It follows the complete working code:

```
augroup PRETTIER
    autocmd! * <buffer>
    autocmd BufWritePre <buffer> call Prettify()
augroup END

def Prettify()
    var win_view = winsaveview()
    silent exe $":%!prettier --prose-wrap always --print-width {&l:textwidth} --stdin-filepath {shellescape(expand("%"))}"
    winrestview(win_view)
enddef
```

Comment: You don’t need to pass the filename when using a stdin/stdout filter, btw.

Comment: Do you mean to remove `shellescape(expand("%"))`? If so, then the buffer is cleaned and I would get the following error: `[error] No parser and no file path given`, couldn't infer a parser. You should use `--stdin-filepath` option though. I am going to update my answer.